# Can I override the default communication / Team Site menu (SPFX)

Tags: spfx-extensions, modern-pages

I know I can use application customiser to add top and bottom placeholders to the new modern pages.
But I'd prefer to use the same existing menu(OTB) but change the datasource to come from a sharepoint list.

Reason is when I view the site on a mobile,tablet device I like the fact that it changes t the hamburger menu on small devices.

Is this something that is possible?
Also can we hide the menu on this modern-ui sites?

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Can anyone comment on this?